# Upload and configure WordPress

Tags: ftp, uploads

I'm trying to install WordPress for my website, and I need it to configure but I don't know how.

The web hosting company does not use cPanel. I downloaded the WordPress .zip file from the official site - wordpress.org, then unzipped and uploaded via FTP client Filezilla. When I open the main domain - stefanpb.com - it shows me an error message.

What am I doing wrong?

www.stefanpb.com/wp-admin

Not Found

The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.stefanpb.com Port 80

Comment: You probably need to start with letting us know what the error message actually is. It would be difficult to determine what you're doing wrong without knowing what actually is wrong.

Comment: It seems that you have uploaded and unzipped Wordpress into wrong directory. Look for a www or htdocs directory and move uploaded file there.

Comment: The error is this : I type www.stefanpb.com/wp-admin and it says : The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.stefanpb.com Port 80      .        Also I was uploaded wordpress unziped in the www directory. Any ideas ?